# setText not displaying variable

Tags: java, android

When I run the app nothing shows up in the TextView. I have a feeling that it has something to do with the onReceive function because when I move it out of the function it displays. If this is the case how would I get the value of the variable outside the function?

I just updated my code to the new way of getting but now i get this error..Any ideas?

> ```
>  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(int)' on a null
> ```
>
> object reference
>               at >
>   com.example.android.login.MainActivity$1.onReceive(MainActivity.java:42)

```
   package com.example.android.login;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.parse.LogOutCallback;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

import com.parse.ParseException;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private TextView batteryPercent;
    public void getBatteryPercentage() {
        BroadcastReceiver batteryLevelReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                context.unregisterReceiver(this);
                int currentLevel = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
                int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
                int level = -1;
                if (currentLevel >= 0 && scale > 0) {
                    level = (currentLevel * 100) / scale;
                }
                batteryPercent.setText(level);
            }
        };
        IntentFilter batteryLevelFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(batteryLevelReceiver, batteryLevelFilter);
    }

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    public Button logoutButton;
    public int level;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        batteryPercent = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.percent);
        getBatteryPercentage();

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_appbar);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        NavigationDrawerFragment drawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout), toolbar);


        logoutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logoutButton);
        logoutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                // Set up a progress dialog
                final ProgressDialog logout = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                logout.setTitle("Please wait.");
                logout.setMessage("Logging out.  Please wait.");
                logout.show();
                ParseUser.logOutInBackground(new LogOutCallback() {

                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        logout.dismiss();
                        if (e == null) {
                            Intent logoutDone = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DispatchActivity.class);
                            startActivity(logoutDone);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Logout Unsuccessful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: Does the code you show compile?

Comment: I think the reason it doesn't is because `findViewbyId()` is searching the activity for the view, so outside of the broadcast receiver it will work fine, but inside, I don't think it can reference the view. If you move the `findViewbyId()` line outside of the broadcast receiver, but leave the `setText()` line inside, it may work.

Comment: Is this inside an activity? You could do `ActivityName.this.findViewById()` to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Can you please post whole code? Atleast registration part of receiver?

Comment: @dharms Your's did not work either.

Comment: can you post the whole code of this activity here?

Comment: Is your receiver ever actually firing? It doesn't seem like you do anything with it after creating it.

Comment: Whatsup with the textview declared final? Remove final declaration. Hope it works.

Comment: @Nevermore it's because he's accessing it from within an anonymous inner class. It's required.

Comment: Try this. Declare the textview outside the onCreate and in onCreate(), do the findViewById( ... )

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `registerReceiver()` to your activity after creating the receiver. Right now you will never have your `onReceive()` code execute.